# How to pass a dictionary as argument to map in concurrent.futures?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the following code from `concurrent.futures` in python

```
   import concurrent.futures
import math
import functools


primes = {"n1": 112272535095293, "n2": 112582705942171, "n3": 4}
t={}

def is_prime(n):
    if primes[n] % 2 == 0:
        t[n]= False
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(primes[n])))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if primes[n] % i == 0:
            t[n]= False
            return False
    t[n]= True
    return True


d = list(primes.keys())


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
        for number, prime in zip(primes, pool.map(is_prime, d)):
            print(number, prime)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    main()
    print(t)
```

1. I want the `t` dictionary holds the result of is_prime. ie t[n] = False, etc
2. How can pass the primes dictionary as argument to the function `is_prime`

Comment: Where exactly do you want to pass the dictionary?  Since you have two variables PRIMES which is a list and primes which is a dictionary, you probably need to substitute primes for PRIMES.  Note that's why it is important to clearly label variables so they are easily distinguishable from one another

Comment: I want to pass primes (lowecase).

Comment: Where, what line of code?

Comment: I asked how to add this line :)